# blur shapes with sharp edges in Adobe XD but not in reality

Tags: android, css, user-interface

I am designing an app and I used shape blur filter on Adobe XD for making an app-bar-bottom which you can see it in below. I wonder, Can I make it for web or mobile? as I know in CSS when we use blur filter that element doesn't have sharp and edge borders!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest/best way to do that, would be to use an image (png). 
Place it using the background property.
Position it where you want it using background-position.
If you use px and not %/em to position it, it will always be in the same place and act as you'd expect it to.

Comment: Why doesn't it? Couldn't you just export it into Photoshop and save it as a png? If you can't do that from within XD? I've not used XD so I don't know what you can and can't do, but I know you could make that object in Photoshop.